# Are observations of events in distant galaxies events that occurred in the past?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

Which of the following is a correct consequence of speed of light in a vacuum being the same for all observers?

A) The frame of reference of the observer is always the real frame of reference

B) Observations of events in distant galaxies are observations of events that occurred in the past

c) A clock that is moving relative to an observer will tick faster than a clock that is at rest in the observer's own frame of reference.

D) When measured by a stationary observer, the length of a moving object is smaller than the length of the object when it is measured in its own frame of reference.

It is clear to me that A) and C) are wrong. I am contemplating between B) and D). D) is the correct answer as given by the book, but it does not explains why the other options are incorrect.

B) sounds like a viable option to me, can someone explains why is B) incorrect? If so, tweak the answer in such way that it becomes the correct answer. Thanks

Comment: Everything we see happened in the past as the speed of light is not instantaneous.

Answer (score 0):

This is such a vague and poorly worded question that it is impossible to be sure what was in the mind of the question setter. But here is my guess.

You could argue that answer (B) is not a consequence of the speed of light being the same for all observers, but is instead a consequence of the *finite* speed of light. If the speed of light was the same for all observers but was *infinite* then (B) would not be true. On the other hand, if the speed of light was finite but *not* the same for all observers then (B) would still be true.

Comment: True, (B) would still be true in your alternative interpretation.  But the truth of (B) is not a consequence of the fact that the speed of light is the same for all observers.  So there is no ambiguity; (B) cannot be the answer.

Comment: @garyp Hey thanks for your comment garyp, but I am still unsure what you mean. Can you provide me a short answer or just commenting? So when we see events in distant galaxies are they events that occurred in the past? If not what is the reason? Many thanks